# Use variable with Dir.glob

Tags: ruby, dir

I am trying to make a small change to a Ruby script so i can specify a folder location at runtime.

I was pretty sure that this would be an easy task, even though i am not a Ruby programmer, but i cannot find the correct syntax.

```
puts "Enter folder name and press enter: "
folder = gets

files = Dir.glob("folder/[0-100]*.txt"); # What is the correct syntax to use, so the content of the variable folder will be used?

puts files
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert a variable (or any ruby expression) into a string, you can use `#{}`:

```
Dir.glob("#{folder}/[0-100]*.txt")
```

Also note that the string returned by `gets` will have a newline (`\n`) at the end, which isn't valid in folder names of course. So you'll have to use the `chomp` method to get rid of that.

Comment: If i write the folder name directly in Dir.glob, like this: Dir.glob("system_logs/[0-100]*.txt") a list of all the log files get written out, but with Dir.glob("#{folder}/[0-100]*.txt") and the same folder name given to gets, nothing is written out?

Comment: @jet: You'll have to do `folder = gets.chomp`, otherwise `folder` will have a newline at the end.